# Как сменить текстовый редактор в AS?

Tags: android-studio

Не могу найти как поменять текстовый редактор в студии. Я пользуюсь терминалом и каждый раз когда я делаю `git commit --am` я хочу, чтоб я оставался в том же окне в стандартном редакторе, а не в том который мне открывается(как то кастомно установленый)

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Лично я нашел такую настройку `File -> Settings -> Terminal -> Shell path`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и здесь вы можете выбрать путь к редактору, а так же я бы вам советовал поковыряться в настройках терминала. Поменяв путь к редактору вы сможете решить вашу проблему, но не факт что другой редактор будет корректно работать с AS. Надеюсь поможет :)

Comment: нет, это путь к терминалу ... можно использовать git bush можно cmd ... а мне нужно поменять другое. Попробуйте сделать `git commit --am` и посмотреть что у вас откроется или вы останетесь в том же окне

Comment: вывело сообщение об неудачном коммите :(

Comment: Вообще не должно быть проблем... Что значит не удачный коммит? Попробуйте `git add .` и потом `git commit --am`

Comment: чет не получается все-равно, ошибка про свап файла какого-то, может как-то по-другому проверить вашу проблему можно?

Comment: а у вас гид установлен вообще? Это просто очень тривиальная команда. Это по сути коммит... Я не понимаю как может не работать комит...

Comment: я честно говоря тоже в замешательстве)) гит есть но я коммиты чаще всего делаю через студийную утилиту